# Heap memory is growing

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management, instruments

Today I made some tests and I am curious of the results. I made an app (ARC) which have UINavigationController and two UIViewControllers. In the first view there is a button and when that button is pressed the second view is loaded. In the second view when shake gesture is detected the first view is loaded and so on. What I notice in instruments is that the heap grows every time when a view is loaded. Here is some code

AppDelegate.m

```
self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]init];
self.window setRootViewController:self.navigationController];
FirstViewController *firstview = [FirstViewController alloc]init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:FirstViewController animated:YES];
```

FirstViewController.m

```
-(IBAction)loadSecondView
{
  SecondViewController *secondview = [SecondViewController alloc]init];
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:secondview animated:YES];
}
```

SecondViewController.m

```
-(IBAction)loadFirstView
{
  FirstViewController *firstview = [FirstViewController alloc]init];
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:first view animated:YES];
}
```

I can't figure out why that happens. How to avoid heap of growing in that case ?

Comment: in your second viewController there will already a back button which automatically works when you tap on it, so no need implement loadFirstView method.because every time you are creatng a new instance of  FirstViewController, that's why memory heap growing every time.

Comment: I don't want that button. I would like to work when shake gesture is detected.

Comment: on shake : [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

Comment: I have already did that but the memory still grow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually every time you are creating a new view controller object.. That should not be done.

So every time you allocate a new object and pushed that view, it will be added to the navigation stack and so, the memory grows.

Instead, when you are in first view and tapped the button, you can pop the  current view controller and inform the `AppDelegate` class to show the second view.

Similarly while in second view, when you want to show the first view, pop the current view and inform the `AppDelegate` class to push the first view controller.

Answer (score 0):

```
SecondViewController *secondview = [[[SecondViewController alloc]init] autorelease];

FirstViewController *firstview = [[[FirstViewController alloc]init] autorelease];
```

you should autorelease viewcontrollers (for not ARC)

if second controller opens first, you should do popViewController. If you wont return back, heap will grow